# Ubuntu crashes after logging in and opening some applications

Tags: boot, firefox, filesystem, 19.10, crash

Everything went smooth until today . I am new to Ubuntu . I have been using Ubuntu 19.10 for 5 months. Let me explain my problem . I was using brave browser . For my online classes i wanted to record it ,so that I can watch it later. I used Kazam recorder and I started recording . After 2 min everything freezed including my mouse , keyboard and everything. I thought the browser or kazam crashed . So I rebooted my laptop. After logging in , I opened Firefox browser and tried to use Google meet for the class but Again Ubuntu crashed . I couldn't find any reasons for it . I tried installing new updates. But it couldn't solve my problem .

I tried to install systemback so that I can reboot it to previous state . But I couldn't install using terminal. It shows some errors. I don't have any access to another computer in this covid time. I need my files and data back . So I can't do anything now .
I had boot repair tool in my pendrive . So I used it . But it Does not help me .

I also tried to upgrade to 20.04 but it is stuck on getting new packages . I tried to use terminal but it shows read only system when I used some commands . Then I used sudo reboot . Now it is not even booting to Ubuntu . It shows only some commands after selecting Ubuntu in the boot menu options . I need my Ubuntu back . Someone please help me to solve this . I can't download Ubuntu ISO file to reinstall . I have access to my phone but that will not help me . I need help .

Sorry for my bad English : )

Comment: "*It shows some errors*" is too vague to help, sorry. Please copy and paste the full output, including error messages, into your question above. It's not are asking clear what question you are asking -- are you asking about crashes or about upgrade errors? They may be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incomplete answer... edits forthcoming...

---

So what did we learn here today? When having system problems, don't panic, don't make so many changes that the system no longer boots. Don't do updates. Don't install new applications. Don't try and upgrade to a newer OS.

---

re: *"Now it is not even booting to Ubuntu . It shows only some commands after selecting Ubuntu in the boot menu"*.

- take a picture of the "commands" and edit them into your question, or post it at imgur.com

---

We'll start with checking your file system, and then your HDD/SSD.

**fsck**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors

**SMART**

- open the `Disks` application
- go to the "hamburger" icon and select SMART Data & Tests
- view the SMART Data
- take screenshot(s) of the scrollable data window
- edit the screenshot(s) into your question, or post them at imgur.com